# "We haven't heard from you in a while so we…" actions should require user prompts

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Just saw, out of the corner of my eye and not in my email inbox or in the notification box at the top of the screen, a message on the job board "We haven't heard from you in a while so we updated your status to X". We will disregard the fact that I do go on the board regularly, at least monthly (I take several job-seeking actions per week, though not all of them are on this particular site).

"We have decided to take X action on your account" is something which should always *REQUIRE* user notification, both by email and in the notification box. I have seen neither a notification in my email inbox nor on the SO site itself.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with that area of the site, could you describe *what* actions are being taken?

Comment: @Rob They changed my job seeking status from actively looking to interested, but not actively looking. I'm unsure of the verbiage.

Comment: One might argue that checking a jobs site once a month is indeed not *"actively looking"*.  You are arguing from the perspective that your status is *your* status - something owned by your account.  It may not be.  It may be the intention of SO to accurately report your level of activity to prospective employers in order to give them some metric of your actual, and not self-reported, level of interest in finding a job.  Consider also abandoned accounts - there needs to be some mechanism to decay "actively looking" dead accounts from the system.  User activity seems a logical way to do this.

Comment: @J...that's not  a reason not to notify the user when that happens, though

Comment: Just a reference, I see you are a resident of New Jersey, where "The Department of Labor and Workforce Development generally considers a minimum of three (3) different employer contacts for each week a reasonable search for work."

Comment: @cwallenpoole are you able to see a Jobs Email section on your Preferences view? http://goo.gl/ke3XgW

Comment: I receive the email every time mine gets switched. I just click on the link to set it back to active. So, SO Jobs is sending it each time. As Donna pointed out, check your email settings. Also, make sure it's not getting filed as spam, which I'm sure you're doing based on your rep points.

Comment: @timster So… who is to determine what "active" means in job hunting? Does it mean that I will actually use Stackoverflow to actually submit a job request? If so, they are doing their users a disservice by allowing people to apply though the companies' own sites. In my particular case, by "once a month" I was stating what I believe to be a good minimal threshold.

Comment: @timster That said, I have been in contact with recruiters and have looked at jobs on the board in the meanwhile. NJ may or may not consider me active at "3/contacts a week", but the very fact that I do search careers means that I am actively interested.

Comment: You say you "Just got a message" notifying you about this thing they did. Why are you complaining about a lack of notification? Do you want *more* notification?

Comment: @J... Yet I never saw a notification in the SE notifications (the number highlighted in red on the top bar), something I read generally daily and I see no relevant communication in my inbox.

Comment: @user2357112 "We've gone ahead and downgraded your account" on a side column of the search page is not the way you are supposed to notify someone. That is [Leopard Notification](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually), a bad policy. This type of change requires an email.

Comment: You should probably make it clearer what notification you got and what notification you expect, then. Perhaps post a screenshot of the bad notification. Right now, your post is quite self-contradictory.

Comment: @Donna Here is my current settings: https://monosnap.com/file/swqMR6UM0bPwraFf8lyRiKxKbhgpFc

Are you saying that this is type of recommendation is a "Feature recommendation", a "Reminder", or "Product information"? I would expect this to be covered under "Account & Security".

Comment: @cwallenpoole  I can see why you might want a notification for this, but at the same time it's really just a reflection of your actual actions.  Nobody can be more acutely aware of what you've been doing than you, so you're the last person who really should need to be notified that you're not actively looking for jobs.  The purpose of the status is to let *others* know what you've been doing.  I don't know how the system works, and this opinion is only really valid if the system will automatically switch your status back to "active" if you spend some time actually actively searching.

Comment: @J... They've come to the conclusion that if you're not *actively* using their tool, then you're not actively looking for a job, which is arrogant and false. I *am* actively looking. But even so, most people would expect notification if a service was cancelled.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Devil's advocate, that's all.  I think if you're just letting a profile float out there and waiting for an offer then that's more "passively" looking rather than "actively" looking - "interested", put another way.  Maybe the SO system is so advanced that you don't actually have to look, mind you.  I don't know.  Maybe the system finds 100% of the potential jobs you could want and notifies you as they arrive - if that's the case then maybe I agree.  Otherwise, I'd think I'd be checking in at least daily to see what's new if I was looking "actively".

Comment: @J... I think they need to better define "active". I get the email egress and I read them (maybe track those emails?). I often read descriptions and have an immediate yay/nay sense without visiting the site, or I'll use my phone (where I generally am not logged in).

Comment: An email seems a bit much, but a notification in the box at the top is unnecessary clutter, I think it's fine as it as, although the message could be made more visible through contrasting colors/larger text/etc...

Comment: @Kevin This notification has significant *_financial_* implications for the user. Sending an email seems important.

Comment: Maybe a checkbox "send me an email when this happens" somewhere, I would get very annoyed if SO started sending me emails about this.

Comment: *"They've come to the conclusion that if you're not actively using their tool, then you're not actively looking for a job"* - What is wrong with that conclusion? You are **not** using their tool, so they switched the status. They didn't block you from whatever other means you're using for job hunt. From the *tools* perspective, you are inactive. I wonder why are you even complaining about a status switch for a tool you are not using. They did the right thing by giving more focus for those actively looking for job using *their* tool.

Comment: Well, I just had this as well - except I am actively looking.  And I've applied for at least 2 roles through the site in the last few weeks - should I file that as a new issue, or keep it here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't receive the email that warned you about your upcoming status change due to a bug on our end. I've fixed this, so you'll now be able to opt in or out of email notification buckets as you wish.

This email is currently bucketed in Reminders, so if you subscribe to that bucket, you'll start receiving these particular emails again.

You're correct that this bucket is not necessarily descriptive of the email type. We're currently in the process of re-naming & re-mapping our emails, as well as improving email settings logic. If you have suggestions about this, please share!

Also - in terms of receiving inbox notifications in the black SE top bar - that's not currently planned, but I think it's a good idea. I'd suggest opening that up as a separate feature request.