# Why would my job search status ever be automatically changed?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I saw this blurb in SO jobs today:

[image: jobsearchstatus]

What is the justification for ever automatically changing someone's job search status? It *has* been a while since I've looked at it, but I'm pretty sure it was set to "Not interested in jobs" previously. It seems pretty presumptuous and intrusive to change this status without explicit consent.

---

The [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323660/we-havent-heard-from-you-in-a-while-so-we-actions-should-require-user-prompt) does not address this question. That question says, "status changes should require user approval" and the pseudo-answer says "sorry you weren't notified of the change, I've fixed that."

The original question is still unanswered: why is SO changing my job search status without my approval?

Comment: I would assume, it's to improve the experience of paying customers such that they aren't filtering through hundreds of thousands of users who've quit the network never to look back who may still have their status set to actively looking. Though, it'd be great to have an actual answer to this that includes the real metric behind it, what kinds of activities count as "active", and how long of a period would need to occur before being automatically switched.

Comment: This is exactly this reason I don’t use Stack Overflow Jobs to look for jobs.  **My profile definitely should never be changed.**

Comment: I have "not interested in jobs" for more than 3 years and is not changed until now. AFAIR, the automatic change to "open but not actively looking" is when you previously set the status as "actively looking" but not doing anything that looks like actively looking for a job (e.g. applying to any company, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to our history log, you changed your status to actively looking 112 weeks ago (sorry, our history always uses weeks and doesn't have an exact date on hover). Three weeks later you were sent an inactivity email asking if you were still actively looking, and another three weeks after that your status was automatically changed to passively looking. This is the only scenario that we ever automatically change a user's status. It was at that status until you changed it to not looking last week.

As for why: you may not realize this but there are two sides to the coin on Jobs. As a user you can search for jobs that interest you and apply for them. But we also provide a candidate search which allows employers to search for users that match certain hiring criteria and reach out to them directly. The active status emphasizes this and kicks users to the front results in those searches. But we want employers to have the best experience possible in filling their jobs and want to make sure that they can more easily reach out to people who *are* actually looking for a job, rather than just users who mark themselves as active and then disappear.

Comment: So my memory was incorrect, and I went from "active" to "inactive". This makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.